# apply effects to a recorded audio using web audio api

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm using the recording voice demo found in the web audio demos.Anyway I want to add an effects to the obtained audio once finished recording.
here is my effect:

```
function createDelay() {
var delayNode = null;
if (window.location.search.substring(1) == "webkit")
    delayNode = audioContext.createDelay();
else
    delayNode = audioContext.createDelay();
delayNode.delayTime.value = parseFloat( document.getElementById("dtime").value );
dtime = delayNode;

var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = parseFloat( document.getElementById("dregen").value );
dregen = gainNode;

gainNode.connect( delayNode );
delayNode.connect( gainNode );
delayNode.connect( wetGain );

return delayNode;
}
```

and here is my success function when recording where the nodes are connected to the destination:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();

// Create an AudioNode from the stream.
realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
audioInput = realAudioInput;
audioInput.connect(inputPoint);
analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );

audioRecorder = new Recorder( inputPoint );

zeroGain = audioContext.createGain();
zeroGain.gain.value = 0.0;
inputPoint.connect( zeroGain );
zeroGain.connect( audioContext.destination );
updateAnalysers();
}
```

so how can I connect the effect to the obtained audio file after recording?in other words how do I connect the wet gain in the gotStream function?

my question might seem little clumsy but I'm very new to javascript especially to web audio

Answer (score 0):

OK. So the demo creates such a graph.

```
realAudioInput -> inputPoint -> audioRecorder -> recorderJSNode -> destination


                       ||    -> zeroGain -> destination


                       ||    -> analyserNode
```

So if you want to add your effect to just the recording, you have to insert it between the `inputPoint` and the 'recorderJSNode'.

The best way of doing that would be something along these lines.

```
var delayNode = createDelay();
inputPoint.connect( delayNode );
audioRecorder = new Recorder( delayNode );
```

instead of just

```
audioRecorder = new Recorder( inputPoint );
```

So your graph would look like this.

```
realAudioInput -> inputPoint -> audioRecorder -> delayNode -> recorderJSNode -> destination


                       ||    -> zeroGain -> destination


                       ||    -> analyserNode
```

Comment: OK. I just realized that you have a something called `wetGain` that you haven't defined. How's that connected?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply effects to the audio ***after*** recording, you can use Web Audio API's [Offline Context](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-offlineaudiocontext-interface).

```
//after the recording is finished

var offlineContext = new webkitOfflineAudioContext();
var source = offlineContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer; //here you set the recording as the buffer
var delay = offlineContext.createDelay();
delay.delayTime.value = 0.2; // set the delay time
source.connect(delay);
delay.connect(offlineContext.destination);

//the success callback
offlineContext.onComplete = function(e){
    //it returns the rendered buffer
    var result = e.renderedBuffer;
};

offlineContext.startRendering(); // start the offline rendering process
```

Since you are using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) in your question, you can get the recorded audio as `Float32Array` using [`recorder.getBuffer`](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) method.

But If you want to record the "wet" signal in real-time, you can just set `Recorder`'s source to be the `DelayNode` rather than input or the "dry" signal.